# Treat @ as text in ToExpression Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have to run `ToExpression["Test@test"]` and I want to return `test@test`, but the
function always return `Test[test]`.

I tried to `Unprotect`, `Clear`, `ClearAll`, `Remove ["@"]` or `[@]`, but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`Test@test` and `Test[test]` are two different notations for the very same Mathematica expression.  If you convert the string `"Test@test"` to a Mathematica expression, any information about *how* it was entered is lost---only the expression structure is retained.

You should tell us *why* you want to "return `test@test`", as you said.  It seems to me you have some serious confusion about how Mathematica works.  Just explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for replay.  I have define some function F[x_, y_] that are working on text and return other text. I call ToExpression to generate a Matrix (outMatrix) with input another Matrix (inMatrix) where I put inside cells the "F[x_,y_]". It returns the right values, but also I need to insert in the inMatrix "test@test" and return test@test. With Math 5.0 was working, now when the ToExpression["Text@Text"] it interprets as you said. So I need to simple remove the role that @ is a function, but simple text as for example does if I replace @ with a or other characters. How to do?